# List - Width is always 100%

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm making some buttons but even through I put the width as auto and set padding, the list still extends 100% of the page. I don't want to set the width in pixels, I just want to set the padding either side.

Can anyone please explain where I have gone wrong:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/KYdnJ/5/

```css
#nav li { 
    color: #333; 
    line-height: 28px; 
    background-color: #F8F8F8; 
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3; 
    padding: 0px 9px 0px 9px; 
    font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 11px; 
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: set margin instead so it is ouside. No need to declare, width:auto, unless for reset. This the default value of block elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List items are similar to [block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes) in that their initial `width` value is equal to `auto` so by  default they will span the width of their containing block if they aren't given a fixed size. You can either float or change the display value to `inline-block;` so that their width "shrinks to fit" its content, or you can just give the list-items a fixed width.

http://jsfiddle.net/KYdnJ/8/

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `display: inline-block` on the list elements. By default they are rendered as block elements, which means they take up 100% of the width of their container.

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents from  my earlier comment about margin instead of padding:
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/KYdnJ/9/

```css
* {
    list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
    color: #333;
    line-height: 28px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
    margin: 0px 9px 0px 9px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: auto;
}

#label {
}

#strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, this is what you want - `display: table;` on your `#nav li` css block.
http://jsfiddle.net/KYdnJ/13/